# RegionPlot3D no longer localizes its arguments?

Tags: plotting, bugs, evaluation, scoping

**Bug introduced after 9, fixed in 12.0.**

---

Just now, I was astonished to find the behavior of `RegionPlot3D` changes somewhere after *v9* . Consider the following sample:

```
z = w;
RegionPlot3D[x^2 + y^3 - z^2 > 0, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}]
```

I don't use `RegionPlot3D` that much,  and thought it's a function that localizes its arguments, so the line `z = w` should not influence the output, and it's exactly the case in *v8*

[image]

and *v9*

[image]

*The warning `Join::heads` in version 9 isn't desired either, but let's ignore it at the moment given this isn't the topic of this post.*

However, things become different at least since *v11.2*:

[image]

and the behavior persists through *v11.3*:

[image]

To make this post a question, let me ask:

Is this a bug, or intentional change? If the latter, is it possible to bring back the old behavior? `Evaluated -> False` doesn't help.

Comment: Sure seems like a bug to me. I can't think of why this would be a desired behaviour. Ask Wolfram, I guess? I had the same issue, macOS 10.14.4 and MMA 11.3.0.

Comment: @MassDefect Confirmed as a bug by WRI. See the answer below for more info.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the info! It seems amazing to me that this bug has been around for so long, especially since I would expect all of their plotting functions to start by localizing variables. Anyway, hopefully by "future release" they mean V12.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Update

Just tested on Wolfram cloud, the bug is fixed in *v12.0*.

---

The following is the reply from WRI:

> Thank you for taking the time to send us this report.
>
> Our developers are aware of this and a correction is being worked on
> for a future release.
>
> A workaround for now is to manually localize the `z` symbol with `Block`.
>
> ```
> z=w;
> Block[{z},RegionPlot3D[x^2+y^3-z^2>0,{x,-2,2},{y,-2,2},{z,-2,2}]]
> ```

So I think it's safe to call it a bug.